# Derivative of the mutual information.

Tags: probability, information-theory

What is the derivative of the mutual information of the $I(X,T)$ with respect to the $p(t|x)$?
$I(X;T) = \sum_{x,t}p(t|x)p(x)\log [p(t|x)/p(x)]$,
based on the paper I just read derivative of the $I(X;T)$ with respect to the $p(t|x)$ is just equal $p(x)[1+\log p(t|x)]-p(x)[1+\log p(t)]$. 
Can you help me to prove it?

Comment: Can you provide a link to that paper?

Comment: Sec: 3.2 of https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/labs/learning/Papers/allerton.pdf @Stelios